# Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/default"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a static page named "default" that have a button "Settings" i.e below

```
<table align="center" width="85%" style="margin-left40px;" >
<tr>
   <td style="color: #212121;">
    <div class="button">
      <%= button_to "Settings", {}, {:class => "buttonhome" } %>
 </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and when I click on button "Settings", it goes on "settings" page, I set the route for it below:

```
get 'settings', :to => redirect('/settings#new')
```

But it gave an error below:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/default"
```

So what should I do, kindly help me waiting for reply. Thanks.

Comment: that error is unrelated to that route. You should provide the code you're using for the button.

Comment: there is no code on the button "Settings" it is on the static page.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line
`<%= button_to "Settings", {}, {:class => "buttonhome" } %>`

It should be:

`<%= button_to "Settings", '/settings', {method: :get, :class => "buttonhome"} %>`